# Cakephp saveAll() Fatal error: Call to a member function getColumnType()

Tags: php, cakephp

So I am creating a form builder. Users will login and then fillout the forms that Admins have created. I am using saveAll() in my "data_controller" "add" method.

This works fine and and looks like this:

```
//debug($this->data); prints the following
//app/controllers/data_controller.php (line 21)

Array
(
    [Datum] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [bool_val] => 1
                    [field_id] => 56
                    [form_id] => 208
                    [user_id] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [bool_val] => 0
                    [field_id] => 64
                    [form_id] => 208
                    [user_id] => 1
                )

        )

)
// data_controller.php
// the  add method is like this
  function add() {
    debug($this->data);
    if (!empty($this->data) ) {
      $this->Datum->create();
      if ($this->Datum->saveAll($this->data['Datum'])) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Datum has been saved', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
      } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Datum could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
      }
    }
    $forms = $this->Datum->Form->find('list');
    $fields = $this->Datum->Field->find('list');
    $users = $this->Datum->User->find('list');
    $statuses = $this->Datum->Status->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('forms', 'fields', 'users', 'statuses'));
  }
```

So that works fine and creates a series of new entries in the "data" table of my MySQL database. My error comes when I try to use "saveAll()" in my "edit" method. I have googled and googled and googled with no luck. All of the articles say that my data structure should be correct, or that is how I am understanding them.

So here is my view. It loops through to output checkboxes and other form elements but we will just look at a simple check box only example.

```
//field_view_datum.ctp
<?php 
//debug($field_datum);
switch ($field['Type']['name']) {

  case "check box" :
    echo "<p>";
    echo $form->label($field['FieldName'][0]['name']);
    echo $form->hidden('Datum.'.$field_datum['id'].'.id', array('value' => $field_datum['id']));
    echo $form->hidden('Datum.'.$field_datum['id'].'.form_id', array('value' => $formID));
    echo $form->hidden('Datum.'.$field_datum['id'].'.field_id', array('value' => $field['id']));
    echo $form->hidden('Datum.'.$field_datum['id'].'.user_id', array('value' => $userID));
    $booly = ($field_datum['bool_val'] == 0) ? false : true;
    $options = array('checked' => $booly);
    echo $form->checkbox('Datum.'.$field_datum['id'].'.bool_val', $options);




    echo "</p>";
  break;
```

My view will output the following HTML to the browser.

```
<p>
  <label for="DatumFieldOne">Field One</label>
  <input type="hidden" id="Datum164Id" value="164" name="data[Datum][164][id]"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="Datum164FormId" value="208" name="data[Datum][164][form_id]"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="Datum164FieldId" value="56" name="data[Datum][164][field_id]"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="Datum164UserId" value="1" name="data[Datum][164][user_id]"/>
  <input type="hidden" value="0" id="Datum164BoolVal_" name="data[Datum][164][bool_val]"/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Datum164BoolVal" value="1" checked="checked" name="data[Datum][164][bool_val]"/>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="DatumFieldTwo">Field Two</label>
  <input type="hidden" id="Datum165Id" value="165" name="data[Datum][165][id]"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="Datum165FormId" value="208" name="data[Datum][165][form_id]"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="Datum165FieldId" value="64" name="data[Datum][165][field_id]"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="Datum165UserId" value="1" name="data[Datum][165][user_id]"/>
  <input type="hidden" value="0" id="Datum165BoolVal_" name="data[Datum][165][bool_val]"/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Datum165BoolVal" value="1" name="data[Datum][165][bool_val]"/>
</p>
```

So then when I submit the form I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getColumnType() on a non-object in /cake/libs/model/model.php on line 949
```

The data I am passing and my controller method look like this:

```
    //debug($this->data['Datum']); prints the following
    app/controllers/data_controller.php (line 39)

    Array
    (
        [164] => Array
            (
                [id] => 164
                [form_id] => 208
                [field_id] => 56
                [user_id] => 1
                [bool_val] => 1
            )

        [165] => Array
            (
                [id] => 165
                [form_id] => 208
                [field_id] => 64
                [user_id] => 1
                [bool_val] => 1
            )

    )

//data_controller.php

  function edit($formid = null) {
    debug($this->data['Datum']);
    if (!empty($this->data) ) {
      if ($this->Datum->saveAll($this->data['Datum'])) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Datum has been saved', true));
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'forms', 'action'=>'index'));
      } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Datum could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'forms', 'action'=>'view', 'id' => '$formid'));
      }
    }
  }
```

Any help that you can give would be much appreciated I have done tons of searching and not found the correct answer. Sorry if this post is a bit long winded.
Thanks,
Devin

[EDIT]

In case you need to look at my model or my table structure.

```
//Model 
//datum.php 
// a basic model nothing unusual here 
<?php 
class Datum extends AppModel { 
  var $name = 'Datum'; 

  var $belongsTo = array( 
    'Form' => array( 
      'className' => 'Form', 
      'foreignKey' => 'form_id', 
      'conditions' => '', 
      'fields' => '', 
      'order' => '' 
    ), 
    'Field' => array( 
      'className' => 'Field', 
      'foreignKey' => 'field_id', 
      'conditions' => '', 
      'fields' => '', 
      'order' => '' 
    ), 
    'User' => array( 
      'className' => 'User', 
      'foreignKey' => 'user_id', 
      'conditions' => '', 
      'fields' => '', 
      'order' => '' 
    ), 
    'Status' => array( 
      'className' => 'Status', 
      'foreignKey' => 'status_id', 
      'conditions' => '', 
      'fields' => '', 
      'order' => '' 
    ) 
  ); 
} 

?> 
//this is from my latest schema snapshot 
  var $data = array( 
    'id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => false, 'default' => 
NULL, 'key' => 'primary'), 
    'form_id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => true, 'default' 
=> NULL), 
    'field_id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => true, 'default' 
=> NULL), 
    'user_id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => true, 'default' 
=> NULL), 
    'status_id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => true, 
'default' => NULL), 
    'value' => array('type' => 'text', 'null' => true, 'default' => 
NULL), 
    'file_path' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => true, 'default' 
=> NULL), 
    'bool_val' => array('type' => 'boolean', 'null' => true, 'default' 
=> '0'),     // I am using MySQL so this is a tinyint(1) 
    'created' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => true, 'default' 
=> NULL), 
    'modified' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => true, 
'default' => NULL), 
    'indexes' => array('PRIMARY' => array('column' => 'id', 'unique' 
=> 1)) 
  );
```

[EDIT]

So I did as one Poster suggested and this is what I got when putting "debug($model);"  on cake/libs/model/model.php (line 949):

```
cake/libs/model/model.php (line 949)

data //this being what debug() returns

Fatal error: Call to a member function getColumnType() on a non-object in /cake/libs/model/model.php on line 950
```

I might see what is wrong my model name is Datum or datum.php not data I have no obvious solution in my head, this is a bit deep in Cake for me. Any Suggestions?

I just took a look at my "view" method  with the same debug statement and it outputs  "Datum" and not "data" like I get from my "edit" method. Just in case that is helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer was delivered in the CakePHP group, see:

http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/759c93f04a626c5b#

Comment: This is infact the solution that solved the error that I was getting.
I am changed my data controller model and most importantly DB table from "data" to "information" and the error disappeared. 

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is true, but I think the input array is not correct. Should look like this:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        [Datum] => array(
             [id] => 164
             [form_id] => 208
             [field_id] => 56
             [user_id] => 1
             [bool_val] => 1
        )
    )
    [1] => array(
        [Datum] => array(
            [id] => 165
            ...
        )
    )
)
```

As mentioned before, I am not quite sure though. If that does not help I would recommend to place a debug($model) at the mentioned line

```
if ($model != $this->alias && isset($this->{$model})) {
    return $this->{$model}->getColumnType($column);
}
```

regards,
harpax

Comment: so changing the array structure did not produce different results. 

So I did as you suggested and this is what I got:
cake/libs/model/model.php (line 949)

data

Fatal error: Call to a member function getColumnType() on a non-object in /cake/libs/model/model.php on line 950

I might see what is wrong my model name is Datum or datum.php not data

I have no obvious solution in my head, this is a bit deep in Cake for me. Any Suggestions?

Comment: I just took a look at my "view" with the same debug statement and it "Datum" printed out and not "data" like I get from my "edit" method. Incase that is helpful to any one

Answer (score 0):

Are you using associated models? I built my first structure with non-associated models and when I associated them I got that same error. I had to go back and change all my save(), find(), etc to explicitly define the field for the controller.

Example:

```
$total = $this->Flo->find('count', array('conditions' => $conditions, 'order' => 'id DESC'));
```

had to become

```
$total = $this->Flo->find('count', array('conditions' => $conditions, 'order' => 'Flo.id DESC'));
```

Not sure is this is the case for you but if you're using associated models I think it's worth a look.